# Turbolinks callback fully loaded page

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onload, turbolinks

I have some images, third-party scripts, plugins (like Facebook and YouTube widgets) and iframes (like YouTube video) on my page, but I need to run a snippet only when all of these are fully loaded (after page change).

Without **Turbolinks** I could solve like this:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
  // snippet goes here
});
```

Is there any way to do this using **Turbolinks**?

---

We can see `page:load` on the [documentation](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks), but it's "similar" to `$(document).on('ready')`, in other words, it's fired when the DOM is loaded, **but not after scripts, images and iframes...**

Answer (score 0):

For anyone seeing this now, this is current for Turbolinks 5:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () {

});
```